# Module blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I am getting module block error when ever I try to import firebase module

My code is as followed :

```
import { initializeApp } from "/firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "/firebase/analytics";
import { getDatabase } from "/firebase/database";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey:"",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
const database = getDatabase(app);
```

My file architecture is :

```
-main|---.firebase
     |---firebase
     |---public
     |---.firebaserc
     |---.gitignore
     |---firebase.json
     |---package-lock.json
     |---package.json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using this line:

```
import { initializeApp } from "/firebase/app";
```

You are requesting the browser to fetch the Firebase App library module from the URL `https://yourproject.web.app/firebase/app`. Because the `.js` extension is missing, the hosting server is trying to send back the page `https://yourproject.web.app/firebase/app.html` with a MIME type of `text/html` (instead of `app.js` with a MIME type of `text/javascript`). Additionally, because this `app.html` probably doesn't exist, it is also sending back a `404.html` page.

---

The modern Firebase libraries are intended to be put through a module bundler like Webpack or Rollup before being served to a browser as covered in the [Firebase Getting Started documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize).

But that document also highlights the following point:

> Do you use ESM and want to use browser modules? Replace all your import lines to use the following pattern:
>
> `import { } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.10.0/firebase-SERVICE.js'`
> (where SERVICE is an SDK name such as `firebase-firestore`).
>
> Using browser modules is a quick way to get started, but we recommend using a module bundler for production.

So to correct your imports, you need to use:

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.10.0/firebase-app.js";
import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.10.0/firebase-analytics.js";
import { getDatabase } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.10.0/firebase-database.js";
```

**Note:** To save future headaches, I recommend learning and setting up your [module bundler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/module-bundling) now.